# Activilty has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42acff18 that was originally added here

Tags: android, onedrive, live-sdk

Im using LiveSDK for Onedrive sign in .it is working but shows warning on rotatating device   on sign page and Authorization page.

Activilty has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@42acff18 that was originally added here......

code is follows

```
class SigninActivity extends Activity implements LiveAuthListener {
private LiveAuthClient signinauth;
public LiveConnectClient client;
private boolean signin = false;
public static final String[] SCOPES = {
        "wl.signin",
        "wl.basic",

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (this.signinauth == null) {
        this.signinauth = new LiveAuthClient(this, LiveSdkContants.CLIENT_ID);
        this.signinauth.login(this, Arrays.asList(SCOPES), this);
    }
    if (signin) {
        System.out.println("Authorization Success");
        finish();
    }
}
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
public void onAuthComplete(LiveStatus status, LiveConnectSession session, Object userState) {
    if (status == LiveStatus.CONNECTED ) {
        System.out.println("Connected");
        signin = true;
        client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
        finish();
    } else {
        client = null;
        signin = false;
        finish();
    }
}

        public void onAuthError(LiveAuthException exception, Object userState) {
    client = null;
    System.out.println("Connection failed");
    this.finish();
}
```

How I can solve this?

Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41d3cf88 that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:402)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
            at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:554)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
            at com.microsoft.live.AuthorizationRequest.execute(AuthorizationRequest.java:344)
            at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:504)
            at com.microsoft.live.LiveAuthClient.login(LiveAuthClient.java:427)
            at com.onedrive.SigninActivity.onResume(SigninActivity.java:303)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1832)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:995)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1939)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:447)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:138)
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5293)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I would suggest you to install Leakcanary on your app and see where the memory leak occurs. Here's the github link: https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Comment: please give your stack trace logcat for force close

Comment: Does this onedrive login open a new dialog over your activity? Bcoz when you change the orientation activity is destroy and created again...so is the context object associated. The context are you used to associate views to an activity.

Comment: I have added stack trace. My understanding is that login and authorization dialogs coming from LiveSDK library. How we can close this?

Answer (score 0):

This exception comes when your parent `Activity` have opened any kin `Foreground`. If Parent activity stops, without closing the `Dialog`, the `Activity` will get above error.

Notes :
**(1)** You should check in `onStop()` method everytime, that if your Dialog is opened then first close that dialog.

**(2)** Before calling `finish()` on your Activity, you should close Dialog everytime if it is opened